# Flutter create has a prblem doing the get cos it thinks my dart version is too low

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter project with flutter create. as part of that i guess it runs flutter pub get. but that fails cos:

```
[chat_app] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in chat_app...                        
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.2.

Because chat_app requires SDK version >=2.15.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because chat_app requires SDK version >=2.15.1 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

when i run dart --version it says

```
Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable) (Tue Dec 14 13:32:21 2021 +0100) on "windows_x64"
```

Im not sure whats happening

Comment: Check the SDK setting in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Check `environment` in pubspec.yaml

Comment: its set to environment:   sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0". But i have that version of dart so i dont know what its complaining about

Comment: What do you get when you run `flutter --version`?

Comment: Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 77d935af4d (6 weeks ago) • 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
Engine • revision 890a5fca2e
Tools • Dart 2.15.1

Comment: i did change it to 2.14.2 in the pupspec jjust to get going and it works, but im curious why this is happening

Comment: @discodowney Dart knows what features is added in each version of Dart. So when Dart is running, it checks the minimum version specified in `environment` to see what features it should enable. This is so your project does not make use of features that is not available in a version your project should be compatible with. It also means it should always be safe to just use latest version of Dart for your projects since the amount of available features is dictated by the `environment` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade your project sdk to 2.15.1.
go to you project folder, open `pubspec.yaml` file and change sdk to 2.15.1

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
```